# Silent install of Android Studio?

Tags: android, windows, batch-file, android-studio

I'm trying to install Android Studio IDE on multiple Windows and I'm having some problems with the parameters.

Since our deployment environment doesn't support the type of packages android studio uses, I did a simple batch file to install Android Studio silently:

```
cmd /c start /wait android-studio-bundle-141.1903250-windows.exe /NCRC /S /D=C:\Android\android-studio\1.41
```

Unfortunately, although the silent install works, the `/D` switch doesn't look like it's working and it installs itself by default in program files.

Comment: Also, is there a way to have only one install template for everyone? For example, a way to setup a centralize Android SDK and never have to specify it for other users?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce your results with the latest version of the installer. So I have reported [it](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=185823)

Comment: I'm still looking into it... can't believe this ain't a working option. If they really want to get rid of eclipse, at least give us the tools to push android studio correctly!